# How to split a string like 1A2B into 1A and 2B in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and am having trouble with tokenizing a string.
If I have a string input of 1A2B, is it possible to split it into two strings, making the output 1A and 2B?

I've tried the StringTokenizer class and String.split() also doesn't do the trick, and I've also tried String.toCharArray() and it also fails because it gives me four outputs(1, A, 2, B) instead of two (1A, 2B).

Comment: Can you elaborate more? It seems you can just call `substring` method

Comment: I suspect you want something like `"1A2B".split("(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])")`, but you should show us a larger sample of data.  What do some of the other strings look like?

Comment: That works well @Tim Beiegeleisen thanks. The other data have the exact same pattern.

Comment: You should still edit your question and make your requirements clear.  Showing us more sample data would go a long way here.

Comment: Are all of your input string 4 chars long? if so use substring

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the **substring** method.

```
String mistring = "1A2B";
String substring1 = mistring.substring(0, 2);  // 1A
String substring2 = mistring.substring(2);     // 2B
```

You can call this method by this two ways:

```
substring(int startIndex)
substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single number, then a single letter, the easiest way is to do it with a loop:

```
String[] result = new String[str.length() / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i += 2) {
  result[i / 2] = result.substring(i, i + 2);
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length() / 2; i++) {
  result[i] = result.substring(2*i, 2*i + 1);
}
```